# Encrypt / anonymize user health data php/mySQLi

Tags: php, json, encryption, mysqli, bcrypt

I'm developing a PHP/MySQLi application that collects basic health data about users (age/height/weight etc) and asks them various questions about their lifestyle (alcohol consumption, happiness at work etc).

I'm currently using salted bcrypt for password security and separate tables for user and health data (connected via User ID) but the client would like the data encrypted as well, and stored in such a way that a hacker could not connect a user in the user table with the data in the data table.

There isn't a huge amount of data to store, I wondered about storing all of the user's health data in JSON and encrypting the JSON with bcrypt, so even if the two tables in the db were linked, the data couldn't be retrieved without knowing the password.

Is there another/better approach? Is there a way to prevent a hacker being able to connect a user in the user table with their data in a data table? How does the industry handle this?

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: bcrypt is not an encryption algorithm, it's a one-way password hashing algorithm. If you "encrypt" your data with bcrypt, you will never be able to get the original data back.

Comment: In any case, tying the data's encryption to the user's password in any way is a bad idea, unless you don't plan to provide any sort of password reset.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm currently using salted bcrypt for password security

Great!

> and separate tables for user and health data (connected via User ID) but the client would like the data encrypted as well, and stored in such a way that a hacker could not connect a user in the user table with the data in the data table.
>
> There isn't a huge amount of data to store, I wondered about storing all of the user's health data in JSON and encrypting the JSON with bcrypt, so even if the two tables in the db were linked, the data couldn't be retrieved without knowing the password.

So, bcrypt isn't an encryption function, it's a password hashing function.

At this point, there's two possibilities that come to mind:

1. You're trying to use bcrypt for encryption, which won't work.
2. You're actually encrypting passwords with blowfish instead of bcrypt, *which is bad!*

If you are using blowfish to encrypt, rather than the bcrypt password hashing function, you should address this immediately. `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` are your friends!

> Is there another/better approach? Is there a way to prevent a hacker being able to connect a user in the user table with their data in a data table?

There's an open source library called [**CipherSweet**](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com) that encrypts data in such a way that you can connect them via an encrypted field with a blind index. The blind index can be constructed in such a way that [allows false positives](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/security#blind-index-information-leaks), and therefore makes it impractical for attackers to use to link tables together.

You're going to most likely end up using the [`EncryptedMultiRows`](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/php/usage#encryptedmultirows) feature of CipherSweet to make this manageable.

> How does the industry handle this?

Poorly. The incumbent solutions shouldn't be used for inspiration. You'll have to be a little avant garde.